# How to create a class in a loop with custom names in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, soap, wsdl

So my program lets me send requests using WSDL the class below is provided by the WSDL:

```
CreateCustomerNoteRequest createCustomerNotesRequestInfo = new CreateCustomerNoteRequest();
```

Using this class I have to set the variables like this:

```
     //FIRST WRITING NOTE TO OLD ACCOUNT TO SAY ITS BEEN COMPRIMISED AND SHOW NEW CUSTOMER NUMBER:
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.UserName = username;
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.Password = password;
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.SystemToken = "sysToken";
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.Note = new CustomerNote();
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.Note.CustomerNumber = cloneCustomerNumber;
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.Note.Category = new CustomerServiceWSDL.LookupItem();
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.Note.Category.Code = "GEN";
            createCustomerNotesRequestInfo.Note.Details = "Account Takeover – Fraud. Acc – " + customerNumberTextBox.Text + " closed as compromised and new account " + newCloneCustomerNumber + " created matching existing data";
```

And to finish off I use this to get my response:

```
   createCustomerNotesResponse = soapClient.CreateCustomerNote(createCustomerNotesRequestInfo);
```

Everything works fine. What I want to do now is because I have multiple Notes I want to loop this process so depending on how many Note there are it would create that many instances.

I do successfully get all the Notes into a list like this using notecount which provides how many number of notes there are (Given by WSDL) so all is good so far:

```
      try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= notesCount; i++)
                {
                    customerNotesArrayList.Add(getCustomerNotesResponse.Notes.Items[i]);
                    //i++;
                }
            }
```

What I want to do: Now depending on the notes count I want to create that many of this:

```
   CreateCustomerNoteRequest createCustomerNotesRequestInfo = new CreateCustomerNoteRequest();
```

I tried this:

```
        for (int i=0; i<=notesCount;i++)
            {
                CreateCustomerNoteRequest a[i] = new CreateCustomerNoteRequest();
            }
```

But its not as easy as that so how can I loop to make this happen?
So I want a1, a2, a3 where Ill then loop all the notes in later which shouldn't be a problem. But creating these in the first place is the problem.

[EDIT]

```
   //Create Notes and copy over array contents...
                CreateCustomerNoteRequest request = new CreateCustomerNoteRequest();
                for (int i = 0; i <= notesCount; i++)
                {
                    request.UserName = username;
                    request.Password = password;
                    request.SystemToken = systemToken;
                    request.Note = new CustomerNote();
                    request.Note.CustomerNumber = newCloneCustomerNumber;
                    request.Note.Category = new CustomerServiceWSDL.LookupItem();
                    request.Note.Category.Code = customerNotesArrayList[i].NoteCategory.Code.ToString();
                    request.Note.Details = customerNotesArrayList[i].NoteText;

                    var response = soapClient.CreateCustomerNote(request);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the array *inside* the loop, which means it won't be available afterwards. Furthermore you need to declare the array size beforehand:

```
CreateCustomerNoteRequest[] a = new CreateCustomerNoteRequest[notesCount];
for (int i = 0; i < notesCount; i++)
{
    a[i] = new CreateCustomerNoteRequest();
}

// now you can use the array outside the loop as well
```

Instead of an array you could choose to use a `List<CreateCustomerNoteRequest>`, which doesn't need a size declaration first.

Note that if you're planning to get the notes inside the same loop, you won't need the array at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < notesCount; i++)
{
    CreateCustomerNoteRequest request = new CreateCustomerNoteRequest();
    var response = soapClient.CreateCustomerNote(request);
    // todo process response
}
```

Comment: Trying the above the loop only happens once, Iv tried for an hour still cant figure it out after fixing bound errors. Please see edit

Comment: In your example you've used `i == notesCount` as a condition in the `for` loop - the loop only continues while the the condition is `true`.

Comment: Changing that to for (int i = 0; i <= notesCount; i++) is only running it once. Creating only one note. When setting int i =1; its not creating anything.

Comment: Did you check the value of `notesCount` then? You can imagine that if `notesCount` is 1, the loop won't run 5 times.

Comment: yes the problem was notesCount variable wasnt even being set :( Fixed now cheers :)